# Customizing the title bar area of a console application

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, console-application

Is it possible for me to either customize the title bar (i.e. change colour) or remove it completely?

Comment: Yh I tried but it didn't work for me :/

Comment: Messing with the default style of windows in your application is: not cool, not hip, not useful, not mature. Sure, change the text to be more useful / informative, but don't do anything else.

Answer (score 29):

Use the `Console.Title` property

Check out this link for an example [Console.Title Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.title)

Comment: Yh I knew about that property but it only allows you to change the text, how would I go about changing it more? and is it possible to remove it/hide it?

Comment: Call: Console.Title = ""; to hide the title

Answer (score 2):

That's not easy to do. The console window is actually handled by a separate process, `conhost.exe`. You'd need to persuade that process to change its behaviour which would involve gross hacks.

You can obtain the window handle readily enough and change basic properties of the window, and hope that `conhost.exe` doesn't change them back. But custom painting of the caption bar would involve injecting code into `conhost.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SetConsoleTitle API. With P/Invoke I would guess.